# Beamer: Why does the title with the comma move up?

Tags: beamer

I'm having difficulties with my header.
I don't understand why the title containing a comma moves up?! I tried to adjust to size of the box but no luck!

You can see that the title on the second frame moves up, compared to the other three. And with a logo in the top right, it just looks ugly. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=2mm,rightskip=2mm,ht=15mm,dp=0ex]{frametitle}
%\hfill\includegraphics[width=25mm,keepaspectratio=true]{thismaimage} \par
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle}}%
\vspace{2mm}\hrule
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\newcommand{\frameee}{
\begin{frame}{TEST}
This is a TEST
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\frameee
\frame{\frametitle{T,EST}This title has a comma}
\frameee
\frameee
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can workaround the issue adding a phantom character of equal depth: `\begin{frame}{\protect\vphantom{,}TEST}` inside your `\frameee` command

Comment: With the comma you are adding depth to text. You could use `\textbf{\strut..` in the definition to make sure that every text has the same depth.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for correcting me. Comment deleted.

Comment: Nevermind. Comment has been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `\hrule` and TeX doesn't insert interline glue before it.

Thus you have two strategies.

### Insert the interline glue

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[
  wd=\paperwidth,
  leftskip=2mm,
  rightskip=2mm,
  ht=15mm,dp=0pt
]{frametitle}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}
%\hspace*{\fill}\includegraphics[width=25mm,keepaspectratio=true]{thismaimage}\par
\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle}}\par
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{2mm}
\hspace*{-\leftskip}\rule{\paperwidth}{.4pt}\hspace*{-\rightskip}
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

### Use a strut

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[
  wd=\paperwidth,
  leftskip=2mm,
  rightskip=2mm,
  ht=15mm,dp=0pt
]{frametitle}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}
%\hspace*{\fill}\includegraphics[width=25mm,keepaspectratio=true]{thismaimage}\par
\textbf{\strut\MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle}}\par
\vspace{2mm}
\hrule
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

Comment: Wow, the `\strut` does the trick!!
Thank you very much, to you too, Ulrike Fischer!